# How do you make a bookmarklet change page icon?

Tags: javascript, favicon, bookmarklet

Before I begin, this is NOT a duplicate.  To explain my goal, I want a bookmark that, when clicked, changes the page icon WITHOUT loading a new tab. Other similar questions gave your bookmarklet an icon, but nothing accomplished what I wanted.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
data:text/html; charset=utf-8, <html><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://link-to-my-icon.info/favicon.ico"></html>
```

It works, but it changes my tab.  I want to keep the tab open, but edit the HTML to change the page icon.  I've tried using

```
javascript: document.write(<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://transparent-favicon.info/favicon.ico">);
```

as well, but it does absolutely nothing, while my first attempt at least changes the icon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/428626) and the [demo](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/dynamic-favicons).

```
//source: https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/428626

document.head || (document.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);

function changeFavicon(src) {
 var link = document.createElement('link'),
     oldLink = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
 link.id = 'dynamic-favicon';
 link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
 link.href = src;
 if (oldLink) {
  document.head.removeChild(oldLink);
 }
 document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```